# R Shiny. Error in :: argument of length 0

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following error appearing when running `R Shiny`:

```
    Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7473
    Warning: Error in :: argument of length 0
    Stack trace (innermost first):
    76: renderPlot [C:\Users\voroneci\Documents\Dissertation\Projecting Swaption Vol\Log Normal Vol Projector App - Using PR2/server.R#162]
    68: output$lognormal2
     1: shiny::runApp
```

App does run locally, however when deploying on shinyapps.io it greys out with the classic message of server being disconnected, I am assuming it is due to this error.

**server.R**:

```
    require(shiny,quietly = TRUE)
require(forecast,quietly = TRUE)
require(rsconnect,quietly = TRUE)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)

load("./PR2.RData")
load("./F1.RData")
load("./F2.RData")
load("./all_data_lognormal.RData")
load("./R.RData")
load("./sigma.RData")
load("./mu.RData")



shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    output$lognormal <- renderPlot({
      all_data              <- all_data[all_data$LogNormalVol>0,]
      all_data$LogNormalVol <- (log10(all_data$LogNormalVol)+1)/0.1

      if(is.null(input$run) |is.na(input$run)  ){
        return()
      }else{
      input$run  
      ahead  <- isolate(input$ahead)
      paths  <- isolate(input$paths)
      und_   <- isolate(input$Underlying)
      exp_   <- isolate(input$Expiry)
      str_   <- isolate(input$Strike)
      seed   <- isolate(input$seed)

      imp    <- subset(all_data,all_data$UND==und_)
      imp    <- subset(imp     ,imp$EXP==exp_)
      imp    <- subset(imp     ,imp$Strike==str_)
      imp    <- imp[!duplicated(imp$Date),]
      imp    <- imp$LogNormalVol/100


      set.seed(seed)

      estimate.I  <- ts(replicate(paths, simulate(model1.3, nsim=ahead, xreg = 1259+1:ahead ,future = TRUE)),start=1259+1)
      estimate.II <- ts(replicate(paths, simulate(model2.3, nsim=ahead, xreg = 1259+1:ahead ,future = TRUE)),start=1259+1)

      predicted.vol <-c() 

      for(i in 1:paths){
        projected.PCs          <- cbind(estimate.I[,i],estimate.II[,i])
        reconstructed.F        <- projected.PCs%*%t(R)[1:2,]
        reconstructed.F_scaled <- matrix(rep(mu,times=nrow(reconstructed.F)),byrow=TRUE,ncol=14) + reconstructed.F * matrix(rep(sigma,times=nrow(reconstructed.F)),byrow=TRUE,ncol=14)

        predict.df      <- data.frame(Date=c(1:ahead),
                                      LogNormalVol=rep(NA,times=length(c(1:ahead))),
                                      UND    = as.numeric(rep(und_,times=length(c(1:ahead)))), 
                                      EXP    = as.numeric(rep(exp_,times=length(c(1:ahead)))), 
                                      Strike = as.numeric(rep(str_,times=length(c(1:ahead)))),
                                      F1 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,1] ,
                                      F2 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,2] ,
                                      F3 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,3] ,
                                      F4 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,4] ,
                                      F5 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,5] ,
                                      F6 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,6] ,
                                      F7 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,7] ,
                                      F8 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,8] ,
                                      F9 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,9] ,
                                      F10=reconstructed.F_scaled[,10],
                                      F11=reconstructed.F_scaled[,11],
                                      F12=reconstructed.F_scaled[,12],
                                      F13=reconstructed.F_scaled[,13],
                                      F14=reconstructed.F_scaled[,14])

        predicted.vol2 <- predict(PR2,newdata=predict.df)
        predicted.vol  <- rbind(predicted.vol,predicted.vol2)
      }
      predicted.vol <-(predicted.vol+1)/0.1
      predicted.vol <- predicted.vol/100
      all       <- cbind(matrix(rep(imp,times=paths),nrow=paths,byrow=TRUE),predicted.vol)

      ylim      <- c(min(all),
                     max(all))


      for(i in 1:paths){
        if(i==1){
          if(length(imp)==0){
            plot(c(0,1),c(0,1),type="n", xlab="",ylab="", xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
            legend(0.15,0.6,"Data not available",cex=1.5)
          }else{
            plot(imp,type="l",xlim=c(0,(length(imp)+ahead)),ylab="Log-Normal Vol", xlab="Steps",cex.lab=0.8,lty=1,lwd=2,col="darkblue",ylim=ylim,
                 main="Zoom In Plot")
            #legend("topleft",c("Observed","Projected"),col=c("darkblue","darkgreen"),lty=1)

          }
        }
        lines(c((length(imp)+1):(length(imp)+ahead)),predicted.vol[i,],col=i,lty=i,lwd=1)
        lines(c(length(imp),length(imp)+1),c(imp[length(imp)],predicted.vol[i,1]),col=i,lty=i,lwd=1)
      }
      }
  })

    output$lognormal2 <- renderPlot({
      all_data              <- all_data[all_data$LogNormalVol>0,]
      all_data$LogNormalVol <- (log10(all_data$LogNormalVol)+1)/0.1

      if(is.null(input$zoom) |is.na(input$zoom)  ){
        return()
      }else{
      input$zoom
      ahead  <- isolate(input$ahead)
      paths  <- isolate(input$paths)
      und_   <- isolate(input$Underlying)
      exp_   <- isolate(input$Expiry)
      str_   <- isolate(input$Strike)
      seed   <- isolate(input$seed)

      imp    <- subset(all_data,all_data$UND==und_)
      imp    <- subset(imp     ,imp$EXP==exp_)
      imp    <- subset(imp     ,imp$Strike==str_)
      imp    <- imp[!duplicated(imp$Date),]
      imp    <- imp$LogNormalVol/100


      set.seed(seed)

      estimate.I  <- ts(replicate(paths, simulate(model1.3, nsim=ahead, xreg = 1259+1:ahead ,future = TRUE)),start=1259+1)
      estimate.II <- ts(replicate(paths, simulate(model2.3, nsim=ahead, xreg = 1259+1:ahead ,future = TRUE)),start=1259+1)

      predicted.vol <-c() 

      for(i in 1:paths){
        projected.PCs          <- cbind(estimate.I[,i],estimate.II[,i])
        reconstructed.F        <- projected.PCs%*%t(R)[1:2,]
        reconstructed.F_scaled <- matrix(rep(mu,times=nrow(reconstructed.F)),byrow=TRUE,ncol=14) + reconstructed.F * matrix(rep(sigma,times=nrow(reconstructed.F)),byrow=TRUE,ncol=14)

        predict.df      <- data.frame(Date=c(1:ahead),
                                      LogNormalVol=rep(NA,times=length(c(1:ahead))),
                                      UND    = as.numeric(rep(und_,times=length(c(1:ahead)))), 
                                      EXP    = as.numeric(rep(exp_,times=length(c(1:ahead)))), 
                                      Strike = as.numeric(rep(str_,times=length(c(1:ahead)))),
                                      F1 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,1] ,
                                      F2 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,2] ,
                                      F3 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,3] ,
                                      F4 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,4] ,
                                      F5 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,5] ,
                                      F6 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,6] ,
                                      F7 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,7] ,
                                      F8 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,8] ,
                                      F9 =reconstructed.F_scaled[,9] ,
                                      F10=reconstructed.F_scaled[,10],
                                      F11=reconstructed.F_scaled[,11],
                                      F12=reconstructed.F_scaled[,12],
                                      F13=reconstructed.F_scaled[,13],
                                      F14=reconstructed.F_scaled[,14])

        predicted.vol2 <- predict(PR2,newdata=predict.df)
        predicted.vol  <- rbind(predicted.vol,predicted.vol2)
      }
      predicted.vol <-(predicted.vol+1)/0.1
      predicted.vol <- predicted.vol/100
        all       <- cbind(matrix(rep(imp,times=paths),nrow=paths,byrow=TRUE),predicted.vol)

        xlim      <- isolate(input$range)
        ylim      <- c(min(all[,isolate(input$range)[1]:(isolate(input$range)[2]-1)]),
                       max(all[,isolate(input$range)[1]:(isolate(input$range)[2]-1)]))


         for(i in 1:paths){
          if(i==1){
          if(length(imp)==0){
            plot(c(0,1),c(0,1),type="n", xlab="",ylab="", xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
            legend(0.15,0.6,"Data not available",cex=1.5)
          }else{
            plot(imp,type="l",xlim=xlim,ylab="Log-Normal Vol", xlab="Steps",cex.lab=0.8,lty=1,lwd=2,col="darkblue",ylim=ylim,
                 main="Zoom In Plot")
            #legend("topleft",c("Observed","Projected"),col=c("darkblue","darkgreen"),lty=1)

            }
        }
        lines(c((length(imp)+1):(length(imp)+ahead)),predicted.vol[i,],col=i,lty=i,lwd=1)
        lines(c(length(imp),length(imp)+1),c(imp[length(imp)],predicted.vol[i,1]),col=i,lty=i,lwd=1)
         }
      }
    })

    output$Range <- renderUI({

      if(is.na(input$ahead)|is.null(input$ahead)){
        return()
      }else{

      ahead  <- input$ahead
      und_   <- input$Underlying
      exp_   <- input$Expiry
      str_   <- input$Strike


      imp    <- subset(all_data,all_data$UND==und_)
      imp    <- subset(imp     ,imp$EXP==exp_)
      imp    <- subset(imp     ,imp$Strike==str_)
      imp    <- imp[!duplicated(imp$Date),]
      imp    <- imp$LogNormalVol/100

      ahead <- input$ahead
      sliderInput("range", "Step Range Zoom In", min=1, max = length(imp)+ahead, value=c(length(imp)-50,length(imp)+ahead),step=1)
      }
    })

   })
```

**ui.R**:

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)
library(shinythemes)
require(rsconnect,quietly = TRUE)

shinyUI(fluidPage(title="Swaption Implied Vol Projector",
                  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),

                  fluidRow(
                  column(3, h2("Swaption Implied Vol Predictor"),
                            h3("Log Normal Vols"),
                            numericInput("ahead", label = "Number of Steps", value = 252),
                            numericInput("paths", label = "Number of Paths", value = 1),
                            numericInput("seed" , label = "Random Seed"    , value = 1)
                            ),
                  column(9,
                            mainPanel(
                              plotOutput("lognormal")
                              )
                            )
                  ),

                  fluidRow(
                    column(3,
                           selectInput("Underlying", label = "Underlying (Years):",
                                       choices = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,15,20,25,30), selected =10),
                           selectInput("Expiry", label ="Expiry (Years):",
                                       choices = c(1/12,3/12,6/12,1,2,3,4,5,7,10,15,20,25,30), selected =10),
                           selectInput("Strike", label ="Strike (%):",
                                       choices = c(-2.5,-2,-1.5,-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5), selected =0),
                           p(actionButton("run",
                                          "Run simulation", icon("random"))),
                           uiOutput("Range"),
                           p(actionButton("zoom",
                                          "Zoom In!"))
                           ),
                    column(9,  
                           mainPanel(
                             tags$style(type="text/css",
                                        ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
                                        ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
                             ),
                            plotOutput("lognormal2")
                            ))
                  )

))
```

Can anyone spot what am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you move the `load` functions inside the server function?

Comment: I get the following:

`Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5658
Warning: Error in :: argument of length 0
Stack trace (innermost first):
    76: renderPlot [C:\Users\voroneci\Documents\Dissertation\Projecting Swaption Vol\Log Normal Vol Projector App - Using PR/server.R#155]
    68: output$lognormal2
     1: shiny::runApp`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try `req(input$run)` instead of using:

```
if(is.null(input$run) |is.na(input$run)  ){
    return()
}
```

For more information, you can refer to RStudio's [article on `req`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Quick response to your question.

I think your error occurs because of this:

```
  if(is.null(input$run) |is.na(input$run)  ){
    return()
  }else{ ....
```

Shiny cannot render NULL values (which is what 'return()' returns). You have an action button in your UI, so you should listen for a click using the 'observeEvent' handler (see [this page](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html))